# global angular-ui-select theme

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, angular-ui

When using `angular-ui-select`, I put `[theme="select2"]` as shown below. Is there anyway to set `theme` globally or inherently, so I do not need to specify it with each `.ui-select-container` class?

```
.ui-select-container[theme="select2"].direction-up .ui-select-dropdown {
  border-radius: 4px;
}
```

Comment: I think `[theme="select2"].direction-up .ui-select-dropdown` should work just the same (But for every element with that same attribute and value)

Comment: hmm what about `.ui-select-container` ?  please explain, i'm a little lost!